# Learn Python the hard way ex 46. Can't make a working module! How does setup.py work?

Tags: python, module, setup.py

I did everything up until the quiz, but I can't get a module to work. I tried using a file with .py extension and doing from test_project import *, then tried using a method in the sum_stuff directory with the file **init**.py . I also tried figuring it out with [setupscript documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) but I can barely understand it. I just started learning about programming and I am usually pretty good at reading boring stuff but it's just way too much stuff to read through and I am dying here. Oh and here is the link to [ex46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) . I really need to learn how setup.py works.

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'This is a test project, I want this module to add a varying amount of numbers',
'author': 'Timothy Law',
'url': 'n/a',
'download_url': 'n/a',
'author_email': 'tplaw@syr.edu',
'version': '0.1',
'install_requires': ['nose'],
'packages': ['sum_stuff'],
'scripts': [],
'name': 'sum_stuff'
}

setup(**config)
```

So that's my setup.py code, it's inside /Users/tplaw/Public/project/test_project along with the thing I think is the module sum_stuff which is a directory that contains _____init_____.py 
here is my code for the sum_stuff _____init_____.py file

```
def sum(*x):
    h = 0
    for i in x:
        h += i
    return h
```

also, I downloaded and installed everything through a virtual environment using help from this https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/
Can anyone help me learn how to do this?

Here is my test_project_test.py code

```
from sum_stuff import *

print sum(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and here is the error when I type it in the terminal

```
its-spdr-2102:LrnPY tplaw$ python test_project_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sum_stuff import *
ImportError: No module named sum_stuff
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the module doesn't work?

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run the test_project_test.py """its-spdr-2102:LrnPY tplaw$ python test_project_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_project_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sum_stuff import *
ImportError: No module named sum_stuff"""

Comment: I just edited my wuestion, thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install your module so it's available:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Dude, I thought it was that, I don't know why I didn't try it. I just got frustrated, thanks! It works*

Comment: another question, will I ever ahve to install this module? Is it there for good?

Comment: Yes, you need to do this to use your module. Python looks for modules in current directory and in some default places (look at `sys.path`) and your module has to be placed in one of these places.

Comment: well, using `python setup.py install` copies the module into your path.